# Testing for letter combinations

Tags: excel, countif

I am building a spreadsheet to identify spelling errors. The spelling word is one cell and another cell contains a formula to determine if the word has certain combinations of letters.

The best I can do is `countif`, but I want to be able to create the return value instead of simply getting a `1` or `0`. I want it to display the missing letter or combination.

```
=countifs(B2,"sw*")
```

This to check that the word `"switch"` was spelled with `"sw"` at the start of it.

With countif I can search for specific letters but only get `1` or `0` return. With IF function I can create the return value but only search for numbers (as I understand it).

Comment: what do you mean by return value ? Can you share an complete example of what you would like to see as result in second column ?

Comment: I would like it to display the missing combination of letters. So if a student spells the word "trapped" as "traped" it displays "pp" in the second column. I am analyzing the types of errors they are making.

Comment: `=IFERROR(FIND("pp",D9,1),"pp")`  .. Would this work ? it will display the char number where the string is, if found, or the string itself if not found.

Comment: That works! Is there a way for it to display nothing if no error is found?

Comment: I have answered :). Also accept it as answer if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(FIND("pp",E14,1),"pp")),"","pp")
```

Flow is: First we are trying to find pp in the text, if yes then it gives you a start number and if no it gives you back pp using `IfError`, after that I have applied a function `IsNumber` to give True if number is returned and False if No Number is detected. Lastly the If statement.